# drupal commerce browsable catalog

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I am finding some troubles how Views works with taxonomy terms. I hope you can help me. :-)

I am building an e-commerce site with Drupal Commerce since it has all features I need for my project requirements but I don't know how I can list terms and nodes belong to concrete taxonomy on Views.

I have a product hierarchy taxonomy with all the site product categories. I use Taxonomy menu in order to show this taxonomy in a menu block allowing the user to select any term. A product display node only can be referenced to a sheet term on the taxonomy tree.

I want to use Views by listing as terms as nodes, if the user click on a non-sheet term on taxonomy menu, the view should show the subterms from clicked term. But in the other hand, if the user clicks in a sheet term then the view should show nodes referenced to the clicked term.

For instance,

Let's imagine I have the next taxonomy menu:

- products

  - term1

    - term1.1
    - term1.2

      - node1
      - node2
    - term1.3
  - term2

    - node3
    - node4

If the user clicks on term1 term the view should list term1.1, term1.2 and term1.3 but if he/she clicks on term1.2 it should list node1 and node2.

How can I do this on Views? How can I list two different types of entities depending what term is clicked?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A view can only ever be based on a single base table, so you can only ever show a single entity type in a single view, unless you relate new types to the base type via a relationship. But that won't get you what you're looking for. To the best of my knowledge you can't use views to make the pages you've described, it'll have to be custom coded

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible in views but you could try a combination of menu block and display suite modules, if you can't custom-code it.

You might also need a module which creates fly-out menus. Display suite is capable of pulling in various entities into your display, and there is a great set of tutorials available on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcT-LcOjgEIkNKdOKwjsZKEPQzNFDtvkH) that will show you how to achieve this.

[This site](http://www.bookfish.co.za) is built with Drupal commerce, display suite and menu blocks; although I didn't add nodes to my menu blocks, it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1jqu8JnLbU). I only had to adapt a little but it worked for me! :-)

See you!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you explain what exactly you did? Link-only answers are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange sites. In its current shape, the answer doesn't help future readers, and that is the aim Stack Exchange has.